# Do we have any example of crowdloan reward distribution implementation?

Tags: crowdloan

I need to implement the crowdloan reward distribution.
Do we have have any reference/example for that?

What are the options we have to distribute the rewards?

Answer (score 1):

First check the code of the [Parachain Crowdloaning pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/crowdloan/mod.rs) which is included in the [Polkadot runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1388).

> The point of this pallet is to allow parachain projects to offer the ability to help fund a deposit for the parachain. When the crowdloan has ended, the funds are returned.

For distributing rewards for crowdloan participation in parachain-native tokens, check this interesting one build from the community: [Crowdloan Rewards Pallet](https://github.com/PureStake/crowdloan-rewards).

Another example see this blog for the [Composable’s Implementation of the Crowdloan Rewards Pallet](https://composablefi.medium.com/composables-implementation-of-the-crowdloan-rewards-pallet-bb08e3f3792f) and [the code of the pallet](https://github.com/ComposableFi/composable/tree/main/code/parachain/frame/crowdloan-rewards).

Other interesting resources for a crowdloan is read the blogs of different parachains that has successfully done one: [Moonbeam](https://moonbeam.foundation/moonbeam-crowdloan/), [Astar](https://medium.com/astar-network/astar-crowdloan-event-part-i-f880988b9685), [Unique Network](https://unique.network/token/crowdloan/) ...