# How we send the crowdloan reward to the parachain wallet?

Tags: account, crowdloan

As you know in crowdloan we the contributor contribute from the polkadot account(1D....).
So according to that how send the reward to the contributors native chain account(XGT...).

How we basically getting the native chain address from polkadot native address?

Comment: take a look into this examples for another question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7026/2762

Comment: Yeah, I got it. but i how we will get the contributors details for which we will calculate the rewards? @AlexBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use transform the address to relay address by format transform

Link: https://polkadot.subscan.io/tools/format_transform

this link will help you to transform the address from any address to any address type in substrate